# Отладка приложения с исходниками Meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor, visual-studio-code

Я новичок в javascript. Использую VSCode. Есть приложение на meteor, при запуске вываливается ошибка `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`
. Решения найденные гуглом не подходят. Хочу попробовать отладить в исходном коде meteor, только не знаю как. Реп meteor c гитхаба клонировал. Какие действия нужны, чтобы появилась возможность устанавливать брейкпоинты в коде meteor?

Comment: Зачем дебажить исходный код метеора? Если вы считаете что ошибка в метеоре, напиши им в github, они очень быстро все правят. Но 99% что это ваша ошибка и дебажить вам нужно ваш код

Comment: @IgorGolovin да, 100% ошибка в моем коде, но проявляется она, когда мой код запускается внутри метеора, и я никак не могу понять, что ему не нравится. Сообщение об ошибке малоинформативно и в гугле целая прорва вариантов, после 10-15 пришел к выводу, что лучше попробовать отладить совместно с метером. Но и здесь оказалось проблем хватает: разрабы категорически не советуют пытаться запустить метеор в режиме разработчика на винде, слишком велика вероятность ошибки, но предоставляют ссылки на методы, предложенные комьюнити.